# Decreasing the distance between node labels and connecting lines in forest

Tags: forest

I use the following code to produce trees like the two left ones in the figure.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges
[S
  [NP [er\\he] ]
  [NP
    [Det [das\\the] ]
    [N [Buch\\book] ] 
  ]
  [NP
    [Det [der\\the] ]
    [N [Frau\\woman] ] 
  ]
  [V [gibt\\gives] ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I would want to decrease this distance so that it looks like the tree on the right (drawn with `tikz-qtree`). Is there a way to do this (and set it as a default)?

[image: different distances between node labels]

Comment: Set `l sep` for the tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like

```
l sep-=<some length>
```

which will reduce the distance between tiers by `<some length>`?

The following compares the default with reductions of `1em` and `2em` respectively:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}},
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges
[S
  [NP [er\\he] ]
  [NP
    [Det [das\\the] ]
    [N [Buch\\book] ]
  ]
  [NP
    [Det [der\\the] ]
    [N [Frau\\woman] ]
  ]
  [V [gibt\\gives] ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep-=1em,
  },
sn edges
[S
  [NP [er\\he] ]
  [NP
    [Det [das\\the] ]
    [N [Buch\\book] ]
  ]
  [NP
    [Det [der\\the] ]
    [N [Frau\\woman] ]
  ]
  [V [gibt\\gives] ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep-=2em,
  },
sn edges
[S
  [NP [er\\he] ]
  [NP
    [Det [das\\the] ]
    [N [Buch\\book] ]
  ]
  [NP
    [Det [der\\the] ]
    [N [Frau\\woman] ]
  ]
  [V [gibt\\gives] ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: effects of decreasing <code>l sep</code>]

Comment: Hm. I am more looking for a general option to change. So, I will put this in the general style definitions. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanMüller Well that is general. You can define it for the whole document. I just did it this way to demonstrate the effect of different settings in a single image.

Comment: why negative values doen't work? l sep=-10mm

Comment: @FiboKowalsky They do, but `l sep` is a minimum distance. Forest will ensure there's at least that much separation. But it will always make sure that the nodes don't overlap, the children are in the correct direction from the parent etc. So setting `l sep` to a negative distance is going to do little or nothing more than setting it to zero.