# Decrease distance between nodes in tree using Forest

Tags: forest

I have many trees in my latex document that are too big and make it hard to make the typesetting of the surrounding text look good. Therefore I want to decrease the vertical length of the tree by decreasing the distance between the nodes. I have tried the solution in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167976/decreasing-the-distance-between-node-labels-and-connecting-lines-in-forest) thread, by including this code:

```
  for tree={
    l sep-=1em,
  },
```

The only effect is that the distance between the node labeled DP and the node Manne, triangle, is decreased. The rest of them stay the same.

I have loaded the `gb4e` package in since I need it in the actual document and no reason related to the actual problem of this post.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest, gb4e}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom{}}},
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,}},   
qtree/.style={
    baseline,
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      inner sep=1pt,
    }},
nice empty nodes/.style={for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}}
}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex 
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep-=1em,
  },
qtree, nice empty nodes,
[TP
    [T]
    [\textit{v}P, 
        [AdvP
            [sneehpeslaakan, triangle]]
        [\textit{v}P
            [DP
                [Manne, triangle]]
            [{}, s sep=15pt
                [VP
                    [DP
                        [gærjah, triangle]]
                    [t{\scriptsize V}]]
                [\textit{v} \\ lohk]]]]]
\end{forest}
%\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Your 'triangle' style isn't defined. Can you add that.

Comment: The problem is caused by the `nice empty nodes` style. If you remove it, the tree gets nicer (except for the empty nodes...).

Comment: I think the 'triangle' is a default. I don not recall having defined it.

Comment: Well as posted the example doesn't compile.

Comment: Is there a way to keep `nice empty nodes` and also alter the distance between the nodes?

Comment: I copied the code from the example above back into my latex editor and it compiled. I don't understand why it wouldn't compile on your end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43544/discussion-between-david-kroik-and-alan-munn).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the way the `nice empty nodes` style is defined. Here's a solution which gives a slightly different definition of `nice empty nodes` which I call `fairly nice empty nodes`. This definition will probably not be as successful with long strings of empty nodes, but for the occasional one as in your tree, it works quite well.

I've made some simplifications to your code, much of which has now been incorporated into the `linguistics` library of `forest`. I've also removed the `utf8x` input encoding, which generally shouldn't be used.  The `triangle` style isn't defined by default, but there is a `roof` style which is, so I've used that instead.  This is using `forest` <del>v. 2.0.3 from TeXLive 2016</del>v. 2.15 from TeXLive 2017. **Code has been updated to reflect recent changes**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest, gb4e}

\forestset{
   fairly nice empty nodes/.style={
        delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,
              for siblings={anchor=north}}{}
              }}}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex 
\begin{forest}
fairly nice empty nodes,
[TP
    [T]
    [\textit{v}P, 
        [AdvP
            [sneehpeslaakan, roof]]
        [\textit{v}P
            [DP
                [Manne, roof]]
            [{}, s sep=15pt
                [VP
                    [DP
                        [gærjah, roof]]
                    [t{\scriptsize V}]]
                [\textit{v} \\ lohk]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you really want to squish the tree further, you can set `l=0` and then change the value of `l sep-` to something a bit smaller. For example, setting

```
for tree={l sep-=.7em,l=0}
```

yields the following output:

[image: squished version]

### Forest v.1 version

It appears you are using `forest` v.1, which is why your code wouldn't compile for me. So here's a version using that version of `forest`. I've left the other code in the answer, since `forest` v.1 is now more than two years old, and hasn't been part of TeX Live since 2014, so other people who find this question (or you, if you update) may find the newer code useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest, gb4e}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom{}}},
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,}},   
qtree/.style={
    baseline,
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      inner sep=1pt,
    }},
nice empty nodes/.style={for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{}}},
fairly nice empty nodes/.style={
            delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={
                  for children={anchor=north}}}{}}
}}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex 
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep-=1em,
  },
qtree, fairly nice empty nodes,
[TP
    [T]
    [\textit{v}P, 
        [AdvP
            [sneehpeslaakan, triangle]]
        [\textit{v}P
            [DP
                [Manne, triangle]]
            [{}, s sep=15pt
                [VP
                    [DP
                        [gærjah, triangle]]
                    [t{\scriptsize V}]]
                [\textit{v} \\ lohk]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `triangle` -> `roof`. Now we have `nice empty nodes`, `pretty nice empty nodes`, `my pretty nice empty nodes` and `fairly nice empty nodes` ... :-)

Comment: @cfr Yes, you were my inspiration. But I didn't want to have a name conflict among `* nice empty nodes` :)

Comment: That is essentially why I used `my pretty nice empty nodes` at some point, I think, to avoid conflict with `pretty nice empty nodes` which was created to avoid conflict with `nice empty nodes` ;).

Comment: I will update the Tex Live distribution to the newest version a shortly, but for present purposes I will stick to the current version.

However, the new version of the example, using `fairly nice empty nodes` still gives rise to the same problem as my original example. Using a negativ value of the `l sep`still only makes the DP _Manne_ smaller, the other nodes have the same distance as when I exclude the command: `for tree={
    l sep-=1em,
  },`

Comment: I updated the MacTex distribution to get the newest version of `Forest`, which now gives me full control over the distance of the nodes.

Comment: With the fairy nice empty nodes I get an error when I don't specify a label for the top node ("nodewalk stepped to the invalid node"). Is there a way around that?

Comment: @GuidoVandenWyngaerd I get no error with the posted code (`forest` 2.15).

Comment: @Alan Munn Your first piece of code typesets fine, but not if I change the [TP [T] ... sequence by [ [T] ... i.e. with an empty node at the top. A workaround is to say [\phantom{TP} [T] ...

Comment: @GuidoVandenWyngaerd Ok. I see. Thanks.  I'll take a look.

Comment: @GuidoVandenWyngaerd This is due to changes in how `forest` handles invalid nodes. I've fixed the code here thanks to [nice empty nodes broken by forest 2.0?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/294245).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for this, works like a charm!