# Tree in forest using the style fairly nice empty nodes on

Tags: linguistics, trees, forest

I am using the `fairly nice empty nodes`-style  from this question: [Decrease distance between nodes in tree using Forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323553/2693) to make a tree with empty nodes that is smaller than what using `nice empty nodes` would generate. However, one node is only fairly nice. Is there a solution or is this the reason for using `fairly` as part of the name of the style.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
fairly nice empty nodes/.style={
            delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for parent={
                  for children={anchor=north}}}{}}
, angled/.style={content/.expanded={$<$\forestov{content}$>$}}
}}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest} fairly nice empty nodes, for tree={l sep-=.2em,l=0}
[CP
    [C, fit=band]
    [TP
        [T, fit=band]
        [\textit{v}P
            [DP\\(EA), fit=band]
            [{}
                [VP
                    [DP\\(IA), fit=band]
                    [V]]                        
                [\textit{v}]]]]]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

The output is as follows. The problem is that the node branching to VP and *v* is branches a little too high, causing the tree to become slightly asymmetrical. What I like to achieve is a straight line between the node *v*P through the empty node and to the node *v*.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like to achieve. Maybe align `EA` and `VP` (and `v`)?

Comment: Updated the question with a clarification.

Comment: Well, what are you prepared to sacrifice? You could let the tree be wider. You could have the angle at the grandparent be smaller. Etc. But if you want a smaller tree, something has to give, basically, in terms of the symmetry. Which do you want to give up?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is what you are prepared to give up when you can't have everything. Having straight (or almost straight) lines makes the tree wider. Using `fit=band` makes the tree *much* wider.

`fairly nice empty nodes` sacrifices straight edges, by not keeping the angles between the edges constant. (It gives up `calign=fixed edge angles`.)

Another possibility is `pretty nice empty nodes` which sacrifices perfectly straight edges. (it gives up `shape=coordinate`.) However, with `fit=band`, this makes the tree very wide as that is the only way to keep the edges (almost) straight.

These styles are required because the tree cannot use `nice empty nodes` since that style turns out to require division by zero in this case, which TikZ can't do. However, `nice empty nodes` would also make the tree wide in conjunction with `fit=band`. So the `fairly`/`pretty` trade-off is not responsible for the mediocre-looking node in your tree. True, `nice empty nodes` would use straight edges, but with `fit=band`, the tree would end up very wide.

This is not a limitation of the software but due to the nature of reality itself. The constraint you are bumping against is a geometrical one and not a style or package one.

Here's one possibility using `pretty nice empty nodes`, which may not be what you want, but demonstrates how to create a compact tree with (almost) straight edges. What is sacrificed here is `fit=band`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  pretty nice empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles,
      parent anchor=children,
      delay={if content={}{
          inner sep=0pt,
          edge path={\noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.children)\forestoption{edge label};}
        }{}}
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  pretty nice empty nodes,
  for tree={%
    l sep-=.2em,
    l=0,
    align=center,
  }
  [CP
    [C]
      [TP
        [T]
        [\textit{v}P
          [DP\\(EA)]
          [
            [VP
              [DP\\(IA)]
              [V]
            ]
            [\textit{v}]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: compact tree with almost straight edges]